# How can I get Tableau Dashboard objects other than the active one using Tableau Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I have a Tableau workbook with 4 dashboards, each dashboard in turn has many worksheets. I'm embedding one dashboard in a Web Application using Tableau JavaScript API.

I can get the current dashboard object using the following code.

```
viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
```

How can I get the other 3 dashboard objects?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Tableau's example that will return your viz based on the hosted URL.

```
<div id="vizContainer"></div>     

function initViz() {
   var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer"),
   url = "https://YOUR-SERVER/views/YOUR-VISUALIZATION";

   var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url); 
}

initViz();
```

[found here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm)

Comment: This is not the answer. use `viz.getWorkBook().getPublishedSheetsInfo()` to get array of `SheetInfo` and then examine `SheetType` of each `SheetInfo` (`WORKSHEET`, `DASHBOARD` or `STORY`).